# SQL - Find records which CONTAIN the same strings and increment reference value

Tags: sql, excel

I've got a set of data that I need to group together by the first reference value found (by doing a CONTAINS search on the Name column) - auto-incrementing by .001 with each additional record found.

Please see below for an example table with the desired format required below:

| Name | Current Reference | DESIRED Reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First Name | 1234.001 | 1234.001 |
| First Name | 4567.001 | 1234.002 |
| First Name Ltd | 7890.001 | 1234.003 |
| First Name and a Second Name Ltd | 6521.001 | 1234.004 |
| Second Name | 4321.001 | 4321.001 |
| Second Name | 5763.001 | 4321.002 |
| Second Name Ltd | 9707.001 | 4321.003 |
| Second Name and a First Name Ltd | 4123.001 | 4321.004 |

I'm not sure whether this is best done via SQL or Excel formula.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method for doing this in Excel, but requires you to sort accordingly prior to inputting these formulas.

First, you can normalize the name using this formula, which will return the text to the left of the 2nd space of the cell and Trim any suffix spaces out of it:

Cell C2:

```
    =TRIM(IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1)),A2,LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1))))
```

Then in cell D2, input this formula, which compares the Normalized Name to the row above it.

```
    =IF(C2=C1,D1+0.001,B2)
```

Drag down both formulas. You can probably combine these two, but it's easier to see what it's doing by separating these steps.

[image]